# Difference between discrete and elliptic Fourier transform

Tags: soft-question, fourier-transform

Can any one please tell me the difference between DFT and EFT in the context of shape description ? I understand DFT but not EFT.

What is the use of EFT? What is the advantage of EFT over DFT ?

Could you please give an example or any document ?

Comment: It seems what you call elliptic Fourier transform is the Fourier series of a closed contour $\gamma(t),t \in [0,1], \gamma(t) \in \mathbb{C}$, or preferably the Fourier series of $\gamma'(t)$. And in the discrete/sampled world, it means computing the DFT of $x_n = \gamma((n+1)/N)-\gamma(n/N)$

Comment: Thank you, but DFT is also used for a closed contour.

Comment: Well no. The DFT transforms any signal $x(n), n \in 0 \ldots N-1$ into a sum of (complex) sines : $x(n) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} X(k) e^{2i \pi kn /N}$ where $X(k)$ is the DFT of $x(n)$

Comment: I do not think so. If you expand the closed contour in polar form, taking the centroid as the origin, then you can have a r-theta signal, which can be transformed using dft.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment.

Comment: You will find plenty of example everywhere, where they are using DFT for shape (closed) analysis.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. And you can parametrize and sample and encode your contour as you want, it is more general to use the length parametrization than the $\theta$ parametrization (that doesn't allow  loops and self-crossing). And in the articles they use a "chain code" which looks to be a very bad idea (because of the $7 \to 0$ that will cause many aliasing and bad reconstruction from the 1st few DFT coefs). Now if you explain what you want to do, it will probably help.

Comment: ok thank you, I will look into this more.

Comment: Why is Fourier series of a closed contour named elliptic Fourier transform? What does word "elliptic" mean?